# How to doing this call back block function?

Tags: objective-c, loops, for-loop, foreach, block

```
for (NSObject *aObj in myObjectArray) {
   [self doSomething:aObj
      completion:^{
      //Execute next aObj
   }];
}
```

Here is a simple for-in loop, which take the `NSObject` out, after that, will take the aObj to pass to `doSomething`, but `doSomething` have a parameter, which is a completions, which is a block....The problem I got is....The next `aObj` must be called before the previous `aObj` is finished. And, after all the `aObj` is finished in `myObjectArray` is finished. It will finish. But what should I write in the completion blocks? I am confuse.

Simulate suitation:

> 1. If the `myObjectArray` have the next `aObj`
> 2. `myObjectArray` take the `aObj`
> 3. the `self` calling `doSomething`
> 4. when `self`doSomething` is finished, completion code will be executed, back to step1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't clear (until your comment on DrummerB's answer) that you really do want sequential operation, not concurrent -- it's not normal that a loop is used for sequential work but in a different thread (though I suppose you want to get off the main thread for your heavy processing).

You can accomplish this using [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
for (__block NSObject *aObj in myObjectArray) {
    [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self doSomething:aObj
            completion:^{
               // nothing special here, since we wait after the operation is queued
             }];
    }];
    [queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
}
```

Note that I've added the `__block` keyword to `aObj` -- potentially needed since you're passing that into a block.

Answer (score 1):

NSArray has a method `enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:` that lets you specify an option to perform the block for each object concurrently. Maybe this is what you're looking for.

```
[array enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent 
                        usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [self doSomething:obj];
    // completion
}];
```

Comment: Sweet! I was working up a simple(?) NSOperationQueue example, but since `NSArray` handles it, things are much nicer this way!

Comment: But the problem I got is ... the next `aObj` MUST need the previous `aObj` is complete, which will call back the completion block. I update the question to clarify my question.